# Динамическое добавление баз для Hibernate

Tags: база-данных, java-ee, hibernate, servlet, glassfish

Всем привет) Извините за мой русский и возможно глупый вопрос...

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно решить следующею проблему, или какие варианты вообще есть в таком случае.

Есть веб приложение построенное на сервлетах с использованием Hibernate(пока что есть возможность изменить его код и передєплоить). На данный момент **программно** вшито использование только 3-х баз данных(по структуре они идентичны ), разница только в их расположении и в наполнении, и для каждой из баз есть свои файлы hibernate-xxx.cfg.xml и hibernate-xxx.reveng.xml.

---

Например, когда сервлет принимает запрос с параметром "base=1", это означает что нужно произвести запись в базу "1" и т.д.. Этот вариант хорош при статичном количестве баз, а если базы будут добавляться - тут я в ступоре.

---

Идеи решения есть разные: от создание отдельной базы где будут сохраняться дополнительные hibernate-xxx.cfg.xml и hibernate-xxx.reveng.xml и сделать дополнительный запрос на их существование как проверку с последующей загрузкой при каждой новой сессией, к постоянному редеплоингу проекта при добавлении новых баз данных(этот вариант вообще не вариант :( ). Динамическое создание hibernate-xxx.cfg.xml и hibernate-xxx.reveng.xml файлов в файловой системе не проходит - нету доступа, из-за настроек среды. Использую  glassfish как веб контейнер.

---

Подскажите, может есть другие механизмы для обхода этой ситуации?

Если некорректно изложил вопрос - буду благодарен за замечание.

Comment: Вообще, по-моему, ваш вопрос убивает саму идею ORM.
Сейчас, на сколько я знаю, в практике заложено, что при каждой правке БД - правится и программа, выделяется новая версия и запускается. Т.е. вот так все кропотливо, красиво и правильно: 
Создается новая таблица, привязывается новый хибернейт-мэпинг, создаются новые POJO-объекты, тестируется все это и выпускается. А ваша идея динамичных баз - это очень опасная практика, которая может привести к тому, что программа выйдет из-под контроля и ее не только сложно, но и невозможно будет поддерживать.

Comment: @АнтонМухин. В любом случае, изменение структуры базы даных, тянет за собой изменение POJO обектов. Но суть разбивки на базы заключаетса в уменшении информации которую серверу баз-даных нужно каждый раз обрабатывать + мозможность переносить отдельные базы на другие машины(взависимости от потребляемых мощостей и ряда других причин)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложите примерно следующую стратегию:

1. Создаете мастер-схему, которая будет подключена всегда. Соответственно, для неё будет свой обычный hibernate.cfg.xml
2. Делаете в этой схеме табличку, в которой храните конфигурации всех баз, которые у вас используются.
3. Создаете шаблон hibernate-xxx.cfg.xml с какими-либо начальными конфигурациями.
4. Делаете API, который вытаскивает конфигурацию из мастер-схемы и проставляет её на шаблонную конфигурацию.
5. Меняете конфигурации райнтайм (подробнее можно почитать [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341871/hibernate-configuration-on-runtime?newreg=c4a834bd0d5444ff9f52c1cc61b5c073)). Можно создать пул конфигов, динамически менять их и тп.